# How to get Google Conversion Pixel Working in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get a Google Adwords conversion pixel working in my rails 4 app. Google told me to add it right above the  tag, but I didn't think it made sense to put it in the application.html.erb file.

So I put it towards the bottom of the code for the purchase receipt page.

I have the Google Tag Assistant on Chrome, and it finds the tag on the purchase receipt, but has a few suggestions about putitng the tag right before the  etc. I'm just unsure if it is working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give some more information on what Tag assitant gives you? Generaly speaking, if GTA returns green, it should work.

Comment: Hi - the tag is blue and has three points: 1. Conversion value not set. 2. Code should be placed directly above the closing <body> tag. 3. Non-standard implementation. I didn't set the value as it is a sign up, and I added the code snippet to the bottom of the view file for my rails app. It seems like it is "working", but it isn't showing any conversion.